# switching between 2 different view controllers that are presented modaly

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have a main UIViewController that is create at startup that I only use to switch between 2 different view controllers that are presented modaly.

Here my code that does the switch:

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController*)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary*)info {

    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:NO];

    PreviewView *previewViewController = [[PreviewViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"PreviewView" bundle:nil];
    previewViewController.delegate = self;
    [self presentModalViewController:previewViewController animated:YES];
    [previewViewController release];
}

- (void)previewViewControllerdoneButtonPressed:(AnotherViewController*)controller  {

    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];

    UIImagePickerController *imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    imagePicker.delegate = self;
    [self presentModalViewController:imagePicker animated:NO];
    [imagePicker release];
}
```

In the first method, the switch works but not in the second. I will like to understand why.

Thanks!

Comment: Just wondering, is there any reason for the 'animated' parameters used  in the dismissModalViewControllerAnimated: and presentModalViewController: methods being different in each method?

Comment: Yes, it's because I want the previewView to be presented/dismissed animated but not the imagePicker. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In the second method you first ask `self` to dismiss. Then you ask `self` again to present a new view controller. This is not correct. You want to ask the 'parent' of AnotherViewController to show the UIImagePickerController.

One thing you could try is to move the dismiss *after* the present.

Comment: I shoud dismiss the current controller (which have been presented in the other method) before presenting the new one, no?